# How to access a model that belongs_to 2 models with all 3 models nested under another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, matrix, associations, rails-models

I'm modelling a decision matrix, so for each **Decision** (n of them), there are x **Alternatives** to choose from and y **Goals** to meet. Each of x*y pairings of Alternative and Goal has a **Score** associated.

Other documentation (listed below) has explained simpler modelling challenges, so I'm still lost. How do I **model the decision matrix** and **use Score attributes**.

Below are code snippets of each model and a test I tried.

Decisions

```
class Decision < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :alternatives, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :goals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :scores, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
end
```

Alternatives

```
class Alternative < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :decision
  has_many :scores, dependent: :destroy
  validates :decision_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
end
```

Goals

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :decision
  has_many :scores, dependent: :destroy
  validates :decision_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :constraint, inclusion: [true, false]
  validates :rank, numericality: {only_integer: true,
                                    greater_than_or_equal_to: 1},
                                    allow_blank: true
  validates :weight, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0,
                                    less_than_or_equal_to: 1},
                                    allow_blank: true
end
```

Score

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :decision
  belongs_to :goal
  belongs_to :alternative
  validates :decision_id, presence: true
  validates :goal_id, presence: true
  validates :alternative_id, presence: true
  validates :rating, numericality: {only_integer: true,
                                    greater_than_or_equal_to: -2,
                                    less_than_or_equal_to: 2},
                                    allow_blank: true
end
```

I tried the following test in decision_test.rb that doesn't work, before realizing how difficult using Score attributes would be.

```
test "associated decision data should be destroyed" do
    @decision.save
    @alternative_1 = @decision.alternatives.create!(name: "toaster")
    @goal_1 = @decision.goals.create!(name: "fast")
    @score_1 = @decision.scores.build(
                    params[:score].merge(:alternative_id => @alternative_1.id,
                                         :goal_id => @goal_1.id)) ## doesn't work
    assert_difference ['Alternative.count','Goal.count'], -1 do
        @decision.destroy
    end
  end
```

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150816211809) do

  create_table "alternatives", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "decision_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.decimal  "score"
  end

  add_index "alternatives", ["decision_id"], name: "index_alternatives_on_decision_id"

  create_table "decisions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "goals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.boolean  "constraint",  default: false
    t.integer  "rank"
    t.decimal  "weight"
    t.integer  "decision_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
  end

  add_index "goals", ["decision_id"], name: "index_goals_on_decision_id"

  create_table "scores", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.decimal  "value"
    t.integer  "decision_id"
    t.integer  "goal_id"
    t.integer  "alternative_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "scores", ["alternative_id"], name: "index_scores_on_alternative_id"
  add_index "scores", ["decision_id"], name: "index_scores_on_decision_id"
  add_index "scores", ["goal_id"], name: "index_scores_on_goal_id"

end
```

Resources (the most relevant ones):

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html
- [Rails belongs_to many models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911890/rails-belongs-to-many-models)
- [can model "belong_to" two other models and have a nested relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401504/can-model-belong-to-two-other-models-and-have-a-nested-relationship)
- [Rails: New entry to a model that belongs_to two other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162570/rails-new-entry-to-a-model-that-belongs-to-two-other)

Comment: do you mind adding to your question the "schema.rb" creation script for the table "scores"?

Comment: It seems like you may be wanting to make use of a polymorphic relationship here, an `accepts_nested_attributes` form of updating, or something involving a `has_many ... :through` type of syntax here.  We really need to see your schema to understand what you're getting at as I suspect you're not architecting your data structure in a good way for this.

Comment: Thanks @TheFabio. I've added it in above.

Comment: @Kelseydh - would a polymorphic relationship maintain the association of a score to both an alternative and goal?

Comment: @purplengineer Where is your schema for Goal, Score, Decision and Alternative?  I see none of these tables in your schema.

Comment: I don't think this is the `schema.rb` file from your question... as the models described on the top of the question are not corresponding to tables in this file. do you mind attaching the correct version of the file?

Comment: @Kelseydh, sorry about that... I've also included the full model file for each of Goal, Score, Decision and Alternative

Comment: @TheFabio, thanks for pointing that out. I replaced the file with the correct one.

Comment: Thank you for the update! (this now shows your model tables are consistent with the relationships of your model classes). The way this is modeled the same `score` row can belong to one or multiple other models (`decisions`,`alternative`,`goals`). is this the intended behavior?

Comment: Is your objective to assign separated scores for each `decisions`,`alternative` and `goals`?

Comment: @TheFabio A score row should always belong to 1 decision, 1 alternative, and 1 goal concurrently. No score should exist without a foreign key to all 3 of these models.

Comment: I forgot to ask... could you please describe the error a little more? What "doesn't work" means? is there an error message?

Comment: @TheFabio It's more than an error as I'm certain there's a better way of modelling it all. Anyhow, the error I got for the test was as follows: NameError: undefined local variable or method `params'

Comment: I updated my answer with a  recommendation for your model. The `params` error is happening because your test function is not defining the `params` hash.

Comment: @TheFabio - If it's possible, how can I define the params hash in a test?

Comment: Just add something like `params[:score]={:rank => 2, :weight => 3}` before the line with `@score_1 = ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a way of how to go about tackling this.

Since each `Decision` has many `Alternatives`(x) and has many `Goals` (y), and these are merely X,Y pairings, those pairings should stored as a join table.  `Score` is this join table, as it essentially represents an `AlternativeGoal` type join table, only it also stores the score value for the X,Y join pair.

To get Decision to link to score you just manually create the relationship when setting the IDs.  My hunch is rails will see the relationship once its been created.  Not ideal (syntax might be off) but I think this might work:

Decision:

```
has_many :alternatives, dependent: :destroy
has_many :goals, dependent: :destroy
has_many :scores, dependent: :destroy, class: Score
```

Alternative:

```
has_many :goals, through: :scores
```

Goal:

```
has_many :alternatives, through: :scores
```

Score:

```
belongs_to :alternative
belongs_to :goal
```

Then your execution would be something along the lines of:

```
@decision.save
@alternative_1 = @decision.alternatives.create!(name: "toaster")
@goal_1 = @decision.goals.create!(name: "fast")
@score_1 = Score.new(alternative_id: @alternative_1.id, goal_id: @goal_1.id, score: params[:score], decision_id: @decision.id)
@score_1.save
```

Then @decision.scores should work.

Comment: Thanks! I replaced my Decision, Goal, Alternative, and Score models with the schema you suggested, but it failed on all 27 tests I had. Maybe I missed something, but decided to undo the changes. With my original situation, I tried the line with " @score_1 = Score.new(alternative_id: ......., rating: 0 " with my parameter ("rating" attribute) entered directly, and my test passed!

Answer (score 0):

I am inclined to agree that the `scores` model is not totally functional the way it is at the moment. It is hard to create its instances through calls to the other related models. I will suggest an improvement for you.

I believe the relationships between `decision`, `alternative` and `goal` are modeled in an appropriate way.

I would suggest you to model `score` in separated from the rest. The `score` class should not `belong_to` the other models. and the other models should not be configured with `has_many :scores`

The table `scores` from your `schemar.rb` could be used in the state you have it.

You could then create a `scores` function on the other three models which would retrieve the `score` model for you, something like:

in `Decisions` model

```
def scores
  Score.where(decision_id:self.id)
end
```

in `Alternatives` model

```
def scores
  Score.where(decision_id:self.decision.id,alternative_id:self.id)
end
```

in `Goals` model

```
def scores
  Score.where(decision_id:self.decision.id,goal_id:self.id)
end
```

This way the matrix that holds the scoring system (`scores`) can be configured in separated.